# Cryo-Tags Suggestion / Proposal (cold stuff)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

I'm trying to define a [QA context](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/143052/ice-world-cryo-world-settlementamorphous-cryolava-cryomagma) about especially cold ice-worlds(maybe they should be called cryo-worlds), where surface temperature range 0-100°K. I noticed there is not a tag for ice-world, nor cryo-world, and [cryogenics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryogenics) tag description says it's reserved for cryogenic hibernation specifically. I did see the ice and dry-ice tags, although dry ice is only about 216.6 °K, and the context I was trying to get at was much colder than that. [According to Wikipedia cryogenic gasses liquify at or below 123°K...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryogenics)

...and so I've used the cryogenics tag, I hope this is not too egregious a violation, although I was thinking I'd like to propose a couple new tags:

-`liquid-nitrogen`
-`absolute-zero` / `zero-Kelvin`

(Also perhaps `liquid-methane`).

**Quick freezing point chart**

```
     freezing points
H2O   273.2 °K  
CO2   216.6 °K
CH4   90.70 °K
CO    68.13 °K
N2    63.15 °K
```

I'd rather not used tags inappropriately if at all possible, but the large discrepancy in temperatures for each of these substances is so broad, and I think could help differentiate different types of cold worlds scenarios for [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based) and [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science) Q&A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cryogenics is the right term for your purposes but the tag definition is incorrect.

The correct solution is perhaps to create a new [cryonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryonics) tag for many of the questions currently tagged [cryogenics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryogenics), and free up cryogenics to be used correctly.

Comment: I've updated Cryogenics, but not created Cryonics

Answer (score 0):

There is a tag for [temperature](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/temperature) with 97 questions so far.

> This tag is for questions which are about temperature, heat and their
>   effects on the environment, the heat of astronomical objects, living
>   being,s things and space and what it might be like. (note: I put in an
>   edit request to fix the commas)

While I see that [cryogenics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryogenics) also exists, I wonder if [temperature](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/temperature) would not be sufficient.

Given that we have [cryogenics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryogenics) it makes sense to make it broader, as Separatrix did.